# Unable to get numbers from window.location.search

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code in my JS file:

```
var match = window.location.search.match(/(\d*)/);
this.room = (match) ? decodeURIComponent(match) : 0;
```

And I am trying to just get the numbers from my URL. For example, in `www.myurl.com/streams228`, I just want to get the `228`.

The issue I am getting is it is just returning `%2`, nothing else, or `0`.

Comment: What is the context of `this`?

Comment: Basically, it was orginally grabbing room?=228  and was working grabbing the 228, however it was checking for room?= as well. Now i've edited my hataccess file so when I go to streams228 it effectively displays streams.php?room=228 

However for some reason the javascript does not get the room=228 anymore but the PHP does. It's strange, I know.

Comment: @JohnMartyn that is because after you removed `?` it is not part of the `search` anymore. Use `window.location.href` or similar property instead.

Comment: The context of this I am not sure, this from a script a friend did for me a few years ago, and I am not too clued up on JS

Comment: `match` is an array, you should use `match[0]`. There's also no need for the capture group.

Comment: If you do a rewrite on the server, the browser doesn't know about it, it only gets sent to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var url ="www.myurl.com/streams228"
var match = url.match(/([\d]+)/g);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to match the pathname. The search refers to the query string.

```
window.location.pathname.match(/(\d*)/)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried  
    var match = window.location.pathname.match(/(\d*)/)
    this.room = (match) ? decodeURIComponent(match) : 0;

to no avail. Same issue, am I missing something?

Comment: try to refine your RegExp

Answer (score 0):

After using the code above from everyone I did this

```
var match = window.location.pathname.match(/([\d]+)/g);
this.room = (match && match[0]) ? decodeURIComponent(match[0]) : 0;
```

and it works perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: Don't copy others' answer.

Comment: I did not copy an answer - I used the samples above and changed my original code based on what I've learned. Posted it so other people can see how I resolved it.